# Why do I need to remove a notification observer before the object I'm observing is deallocated?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html:

> You must invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by
>   addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated

Why does it matter that I stop observing before the object whose notifications I'm observing is deallocated? I understand why *I* as the observer need to stop observing if *I'm* going to disappear and the block depends on my existence, but I don't understand why the lifetime of the observed object matters. Am I misinterpreting this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand why I as the observer need to stop observing if I'm going to disappear and the block depends on my existence, but I don't understand why the lifetime of the observed object matters.

I think that a possible explanation is the following.

`addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock` description says:

> Adds an entry to the receiver’s dispatch table with a notification queue and a block to add to the queue, and optional criteria: notification name and sender.

"sender" in this context is just another name for the `object` parameter, which is described in the following terms:

> The object whose notifications you want to add the block to the operation queue.
>   If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to add the block to the operation queue.

So, `object` acts as a sort of filter: when a notification comes in, the notification center decides based on that value (if present) if the block must be added to the specified operation queue.

Now, consider this:

1. the observed object is deallocated without the observer to be removed;
2. a different object, also able to post notifications is created, and it happens it has the same address as the object deallocated at point 1;
3. now the observer will react to notifications posted by the second object.

I admit it is a pretty rare case, but it might happen, so you better code against it.

Answer (score -1):

If u don't remove observer, it may leed to a situation when you already destroyed an object but it is still sent notifications - this will cause "message sent to deallocated instance" error

Comment: Right but that's if *I* disappear as the observer. The documentation seems to suggest that I need to remove myself before the object I'm observing disappears, since it says "any object specified by addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated"

Comment: No,u don't need remove yourself before object You are observing disappears. There is no sense in it. Documentation affects only the object, which was marked to be an observer.

Comment: Well, what object it talking about then? This method registers a block to observe the notification, not an object + selector. The block already retains whatever it holds.